# How to set a dedicated quartz worker thread for a specific job?

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I was wondering if is possible to configure quartz to execute a job under a dedicated worker thread. In another words, say I have quartz configured with a *SimpleThreadPool* of size 5. And I have a job that fires every 10 seconds, and i want a dedicated worker thread to run this job. Is there a way to configure quartz trigger|job|scheduler to do that?

Other workers in thread pool may free to execute any others jobs scheduled.

I want that specific job execute with no time waiting, if other workers are busy.

Comment: I posted this question in the quartz email group _quartz-scheduler@googlegroups.com_, and **James House** email me saing: 
-"Not possible, no.

Could be a feature.  Contributions are welcome." 

So, is it possible a workaround for this ?